# How to extrude a face without it becoming another object?

Tags: modeling

[image: extruded face]

Whenever I extrude a face, I get this line between it and the original shape I extruded from. How can I extend my cube without leaving this line behind, and maintaining the original as one shape?

Comment: I don't think you can, you can dissolve it afterwards (Ctrl X) but it may be better to keep it anyway

Comment: You can't. That's how it works! You won't be able to see the original edge once you render the final object anyway and you'd have an ngon with more than 4 sides if you did delete it so leave well alone!